# All data gone after upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 through bootable installer

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, data-recovery

I upgraded by downloading Ubuntu 15.04 and saving to a USB drive. I then unpacked all the files and booted my PC from the USB drive. This activated the install process for 15.05. I selected the install approached that upgraded my 14.04 version to the 15.04 version of Ubuntu.

*It said all my files would be saved.*

When the install finished no files from my 14.04 version were available in the 15.04 version. The document folder was empty. The music folder was empty. The pictures folder was empty. There were no emails and addresses in Thunderbird. It was as if it was a completely clean install which didn't bring across the files from the 14.04 version.

*Are the files created with the 14.04 version of Ubuntu able to be restored or recovered?*

Comment: "none of files and settings came across" What files and settings? Also how did you upgrade? You can not upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 directly, did you mean maybe you installed 15.04 over 14.04?

Comment: Can you eloborate on this? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade procedure? Where were the files stored before the upgrade procedure? Please specify a full path name. Are there any other partitions with file systems, that the previous data may be on?

Comment: Hi Everyone.  Thanks for looking at my problem. I have now discovered that the Home folder in the Computer folder has two high level folders. One is the new one created from the install of 15.04 (the default Home folder) and one is the old one from the previous 14.04 version.  So I have found the files.  I've still lost the address book from the previously version of Thunderbird (14.04) so would appreciate any assistance with locating that.  Thanks from an inexperienced Ubuntu user.